# UIButton matrix - cannot present it correctly

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uibutton

I want to have a 9x9 2d array (matrix) of UIButtons.
This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        var x = 0
        var y = 0
        while(x<10){
           while(y<10){
                
                let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (x+1)*50, y: (y+1)*50, width: 50, height: 50))
                button.backgroundColor = .green
                button.setTitle("(" + String(x) + ", " + String(y) + ")", for: .normal)
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

                self.view.addSubview(button)
                y+=1
            }
            x+=1
        }
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Button " + sender.title(for: .normal)! + " tapped")
    }
}
```

It looks like this: [image: Screenshot (only shows the x=0 row)]

Does anyone sees the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Forget about the button. Just print x and print y. You'll see. You need to "reset "y". Can be done after the line `x+=1`, you need then `y = 0`, or using the same logic, put `var y = 0`, just before the while y.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var x = 0
        
        while(x<10){
           var y = 0
           while(y<10){
                
                let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (x+1)*50, y: (y+1)*50, width: 50, height: 50))
                button.backgroundColor = .green
                button.setTitle("(" + String(x) + ", " + String(y) + ")", for: .normal)
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

                self.view.addSubview(button)
                y+=1
            }
            x+=1
        }
```

Yo didn't reseted your y variable between x rows

but i think better would be to use UIStackViews for it